# How we can handle windows authentication in desktop safari browser

Tags: selenium, safari

Currently we are automating  a website which is showing  windows authentication popup  before launching the home page by selenium scripts .  We tried to add the credential details as part of the URL. but we are not able to bye-pass the credential window . We are able to  bye-pass it in  Chrome/Firefox browser . But it is not working in  DESKTOP safari . could you please help  to fix the issue

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. It is a known issue with Safari and Edge drivers, and is not supported behavior.

https://github.com/w3c/webdriver/issues/385

https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/5610

https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/29598/how-to-bypass-basic-authentication-in-safari-10-with-selenium